# Why does my iptables firewall block all sites except Google sites?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, firewall, iptables

Thanks so much for taking the time to help me with this problem I'm attempting to solve.

I'm using a Raspberry Pi4 running on the Raspbian (Debian-derived) distro.

I'm learning a lot about setting up firewall rules with iptables. I'd like to block access to all internet sites via the browser.

I've added the following rule:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j REJECT
```

My understanding is that this command should append (-A) a rule to the OUTPUT chain that rejects any outbound requests using the tcp protocol (-p).

What I expect to happen here is that any connections to sites via my browser should be blocked. This seems to work for all sites except Google sites, like [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) or docs.google.com. I'm not sure why, but those sites are still accessible.

I've also tried the following rule which would drop any requests via my wifi network device.

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o wlan0 -j DROP
```

What I expected to happen here is the same. But, again, connections to Google sites go through.

Printout of iptables -L:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
IN_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
FWDI_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
FWDO_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED

Chain FWDI_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

This line is the one I added:

```
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

It appears under the Chain OUTPUT section:

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe in Dual Stack ( IPv6 & IPv4 )? - Then use ip6tables too

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. Can you clarify please? @koyaanisqatsi

Comment: Modern OSes by default prefer IPv6 over IPv4.  The ruleset you're showing is IPv4.  Check the rules you're using for v6 `ip6tables -l -n` ... it could also be that google (you're using chrome?) uses [QUIC](https://www.chromium.org/quic), which is UDP based ...

Comment: Voting to close as this is **not** a programming question.  Try [unix.se] **or** [su].

Comment: @gmc check out in Browser: http://[2607:f8b0:4006:808::2004]/ when it works than you have to use ip6tables too - Also try: ```nslookup www.google.com 1.1.1.1``` for that IPv6

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi thank you. that was the issue. I had to use the following command to disable the connection to Google's sites: sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -j REJECT

Answer (score 1):

It's probably being accepted by one of the earlier targets. Try (from the console) moving it up to the beginning, I think it would be `-I OUTPUT 1` (Insert in `OUTPUT` before 1) instead of  `-A`.  There is a `-v` option with `-L` to print counters; do a bunch of Google connections to find out which rule the packets are falling under which rule to help debug. But it appears that Raspbian is configured out of the box to use the `ufw` firewall; you might do some searching on how to configure that instead. Adding your own IP tables entries may conflict. Try `sudo ufw status verbose` or `man ufw`.

Comment: Good idea. I deleted it then added it to with `iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -j REJECT`. That added it to the first position rather than adding it to the end, but that had no effect unfortunately. Regarding `ufw`, I have it disabled currently.

Comment: Are any counters going up with Google traffic, say in the FORWARD table for example? @gmc